# Angular error handling using catchError(somefunctionthatreturnsanobservable)

Tags: angular, rxjs

Going through the Angular docs for handling HTTP error responses in a service I came across something like this:

```
getContext(){
   return this.http.post(this.testUrl, {})
       .pipe(
           catchError(this.handleError)
       )
}

handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse){
    if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
        console.log('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
        console.log(
            `Backend returned code ${error.status}` +
            `body was ${error.error}`
        )
    }
    return throwError('Need to fix!');
}
```

I was wondering why `this.handleError` is not passed an argument (an `HTTPErrorResponse`) and how it works without receiving one?

Comment: `catchError(this.handleError)` is equal **here** to `catchError(error => this.handleError(error))`

Comment: @Kos Ah I see. Is this syntax used when there is only one argument passed to a function that only receives one argument? I.e. catchError(function(error){ this.handleError(error) })

Comment: yep! Theres one important difference though: calling context would be undefined when called like `catchError(this.handleError)`. Read it rather as `catchError(err => { const fn = this.handleError; return fn(err); })`. Here **this** wont be the context of the call anymore, context would be empty. So you wont be able to refer to `this` in the `handleError` method.

Comment: @Kos Gotcha! Thanks.

Comment: About how to throw correctly in rxjs I can recomment two articles:
https://medium.com/@alexanderposhtaruk/rx-js-replywhen-use-case-in-iframe-d-angular-spa-d86d35d3bce8
and
https://blog.angularindepth.com/throwerror-is-not-throw-error-ad6c76c53377

Answer (score 0):

The `handleError` method is passed as a callback to `catchError`.

```
doSomething(callback) {
    // Call the callback with arguments
    callback('Hello world');
}
```

```
saySomething(param) {
   console.log(param);
}
```

```
doSomething(saySomething);
```

Try to imagine `catchError` is doing the same for your `handleError` function. Will call it with arguments, you just specify what function to be called when an error occurs.

Good luck!